# Método update do Chart.js apresenta erro "bar.save is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) para plotar gráficos, mas o problema ocorre quando tento atualizar o mesmo utilizando o método `update()`.

```
myBar.datasets[0].bars[0]=10;
myBar.update();
```

Então recebo o seguinte erro:

> "TypeError: bar.save is not a function"

Alguém já conseguiu utilizar esse método com sucesso?

Comment: Pode colocar o seu objeto `myBar`...

Comment: Provavelmente os elementos de `bars` não são inteiros, mas objetos com um método `save`. Veja no [código-fonte](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js) as funções `update` e `eachBars` (linha 2080). Tem certeza que essa é a forma correta de se alterar um gráfico? Não é `...bars[0].algumaOutraCoisa = 10`?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo [a documentação](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), a forma correta de se atualizar um valor no gráfico de barras é:

```
myBar.datasets[0].bars[0].value = 10;
myBar.update();
```

Da forma como você está fazendo, não é o valor do `bar` que você está atribuindo, e sim o `bar` **inteiro**. Quando o `update` tenta salvar o `bar`, ele não consegue achar o método `save` (pois inteiros não têm `save`), daí o erro que você encontrou:

```
update : function(){
    ...
    this.eachBars(function(bar){
        bar.save(); // Aqui ocorreu o erro
    });
    ...
},
```